# riscv64-linux-gnu-gcc indicates "no such file or directory" when I use Makefile

Tags: gcc, makefile, operating-system, gnu-make, riscv

This is the structure of my project:
`

```
.
├── Makefile
├── arch
│   └── riscv
│       ├── Makefile
│       ├── include
│       │   ├── defs.h
│       │   ├── mm.h
│       │   ├── proc.h
│       │   └── sbi.h
│       └── kernel
│           ├── Makefile
│           ├── clock.c
│           ├── entry.S
│           ├── head.S
│           ├── mm.c
│           ├── proc.c
│           ├── sbi.c
│           ├── trap.c
│           ├── vm.c
│           └── vmlinux.lds.S
├── include
│   ├── printk.h
│   ├── rand.h
│   ├── stddef.h
│   ├── string.h
│   └── types.h
├── init
│   ├── Makefile
│   ├── main.c
│   └── test.c
└── lib
    ├── Makefile
    ├── printk.c
    ├── rand.c
    └── string.c

7 directories, 28 files
```

`I include ./include/types.h in ./arch/riscv/include/defs.h, and I successfully compiled .o file of all .c file in`./arch/riscv/include/kernel`, but something goes wrong when compile` ./arch/riscv/include/kernel/vmlinux.lds.S`, it says:

```
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/micheal/courses/zjuos/src/lab4/arch/riscv/kernel'
riscv64-linux-gnu-gcc -E -P -I../include -o vmlinux.lds vmlinux.lds.S
In file included from vmlinux.lds.S:1:
../include/defs.h:3:10: fatal error: types.h: No such file or directory
    3 | #include "types.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

How can I fix it? It is really strange that other .c file also include defs.h, but they compiled well, only vmlinux.ld.S goes wrong.

the top level Makefile looks like:

```
export
CROSS_=riscv64-linux-gnu-
GCC=${CROSS_}gcc
LD=${CROSS_}ld
OBJCOPY=${CROSS_}objcopy

ISA=rv64imafd
ABI=lp64

INCLUDE = -I $(shell pwd)/include -I $(shell pwd)/arch/riscv/include
CF = -march=$(ISA) -mabi=$(ABI) -mcmodel=medany -fno-builtin -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -nostartfiles -nostdlib -nostdinc -static -lgcc -Wl,--nmagic -Wl,--gc-sections -g
CFLAG = ${CF} ${INCLUDE} -D DSJF

.PHONY:all run debug clean
all:
    ${MAKE} -C lib all
    ${MAKE} -C init all
    ${MAKE} -C arch/riscv all
    @echo -e '\n'Build Finished OK

run: all
    @echo Launch the qemu ......
    @qemu-system-riscv64 -nographic -machine virt -kernel vmlinux -bios ~/opensbi/build/platform/generic/firmware/fw_jump.bin

debug: all
    @echo Launch the qemu for debug ......
    @qemu-system-riscv64 -nographic -machine virt -kernel vmlinux -bios ~/opensbi/build/platform/generic/firmware/fw_jump.bin -S -s

clean:
    ${MAKE} -C lib clean
    ${MAKE} -C init clean
    ${MAKE} -C arch/riscv clean
    $(shell test -f vmlinux && rm vmlinux)
    $(shell test -f System.map && rm System.map)
    @echo -e '\n'Clean Finished
```

the trouble making Makefile looks like:

```
ASM_SRC     = $(filter-out vmlinux.lds.S,$(sort $(wildcard *.S)))
C_SRC       = $(sort $(wildcard *.c))
OBJ         = $(patsubst %.S,%.o,$(ASM_SRC)) $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(C_SRC))

all:$(OBJ) vmlinux.lds

vmlinux.lds: vmlinux.lds.S
    $(GCC) -E -P -I../include -o $@ $^

%.o:%.S
    ${GCC}  ${CFLAG} -c $<

%.o:%.c
    ${GCC}  ${CFLAG} -c $<

clean:
    $(shell rm *.o vmlinux.lds 2>/dev/null)
```

I tried to change `$(GCC) -E -P -I../include -o $@ $^` to `$(GCC) -E -P {include} -o $@ $^`, but it says:

```
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/micheal/courses/zjuos/src/lab4/arch/riscv/kernel'
riscv64-linux-gnu-gcc -E -P -I /home/micheal/courses/zjuos/src/lab4/include -I /home/micheal/courses/zjuos/src/lab4/arch/riscv/include -o vmlinux.lds vmlinux.lds.S
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/micheal/courses/zjuos/src/lab4/arch/riscv/kernel'
riscv64-linux-gnu-ld -T kernel/vmlinux.lds kernel/*.o ../../init/*.o ../../lib/*.o -o ../../vmlinux 
riscv64-linux-gnu-ld:kernel/vmlinux.lds:1: syntax error
```

Comment: From the error, `riscv64-linux-gnu-gcc -E -P -I../include -o vmlinux.lds vmlinux.lds.S`, where there's only `-I../include`, header files are only searched from this directory but not the top `include` directory

Comment: I change it to `-I ../include ../../../include` but the complier still can't find the header file @Wanghz